# OpenGL/Java slicing dataset and plotting it

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

My task is to create an OpenGL Java program which will load a dataset, and then display an orthogonal slice of said data on the X, Y and Z axis. I'm new to OpenGL and I've been having trouble with plotting the data. The class to load the dataset has been provided for me:

```
public class VolumetricDataSet {

private final int[]     dimensions;
private int             maxValue;
private int             minValue;
private final int[][][] volumeData;

/**
 * Construct a new dataset from a File.
 *
 * @param in
 *            the file to read the data from.
 * @param xSize
 *            the maximal x dimension to use.
 * @param ySize
 *            the maximal y dimension to use.
 * @param zSize
 *            the maximal z dimension to use.
 * @throws IOException
 *             if the underlying reader encounters an error.
 * @throws FileNotFoundException
 *             if the file cannot be found.
 */
public VolumetricDataSet(final File in, final int xSize, final int ySize,
        final int zSize) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {

    this(new FileInputStream(in), xSize, ySize, zSize);

}

/**
 * Construct a new dataset.
 *
 * @param in
 *            the stream to read the data from.
 * @param xSize
 *            the maximal x dimension to use.
 * @param ySize
 *            the maximal y dimension to use.
 * @param zSize
 *            the maximal z dimension to use.
 * @throws IOException
 *             if the underlying reader encounters an error.
 */
public VolumetricDataSet(final InputStream in, final int xSize,
        final int ySize, final int zSize) throws IOException {

    int value = 0, xCur = 0, yCur = 0, zCur = 0;
    volumeData = new int[xSize][ySize][zSize];
    while ((value = in.read()) != -1) {
        volumeData[xCur][yCur][zCur] = value;

        if (value > maxValue)
            maxValue = value;
        if (value < minValue)
            minValue = value;

        if (++xCur == xSize) {
            xCur = 0;
            if (++yCur == ySize) {
                yCur = 0;
                zCur++;
            }
        }
    }
    dimensions = new int[] { xSize, ySize, zSize };
}

/**
 * Retrieve the length of the x y z dimensions of the data set. 3 element array
 *
 * @return the dimensions.
 */
public int[] getDimensions() 
{
    return dimensions;
}

/**
 * @return the maximal value
 */
public int getMaxValue() 
{
    return maxValue;
}

/**
 * @return the minimal value.
 */
public int getMinValue() 
{
    return minValue;
}

/**
 * @return the entire data set as a 3-D array. x is the 1st dimension, y the
 *         2nd and z the 3rd.
 */
public int[][][] getVolumeData() 
{
    return volumeData;
}

}
```

My code to display the data:

```
VolumetricDataSet ds = new VolumetricDataSet(new File("C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\Work\\Comp Graphics\\marschnerlobb.raw.gz"), 41, 41, 41);

int[][][] volumeData = ds.getVolumeData();
int[] dimensions = ds.getDimensions();

for(int i = 0; i < dimensions[0]; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < dimensions[1]; j++)
            {
                if(volumeData[i][j][0] < 1)
                {
                    gl.glColor3f(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
                    gl.glPointSize(10);
                    gl.glBegin(GL.GL_POINTS);
                    gl.glVertex2i(i, j);
                }
                else if(volumeData[i][j][0] < 40)
                {
                    gl.glColor3f(0.0f,0.0f,0.1f);
                    gl.glPointSize(10);
                    gl.glBegin(GL.GL_POINTS);
                    gl.glVertex2i(i, j);
                }
                else if(volumeData[i][j][0] < 80)
                {
                    gl.glColor3f(0.0f,0.0f,0.2f);
                    gl.glPointSize(10);
                    gl.glBegin(GL.GL_POINTS);
                    gl.glVertex2i(i, j);
                }
                else if(volumeData[i][j][0] < 120)
                {
                    gl.glColor3f(0.0f,0.0f,0.3f);
                    gl.glPointSize(10);
                    gl.glBegin(GL.GL_POINTS);
                    gl.glVertex2i(i, j);
                }
                else if(volumeData[i][j][0] < 160)
                {
                    gl.glColor3f(0.0f,0.0f,0.4f);
                    gl.glPointSize(10);
                    gl.glBegin(GL.GL_POINTS);
                    gl.glVertex2i(i, j);
                }
                else if(volumeData[i][j][0] < 200)
                {
                    gl.glColor3f(0.0f,0.0f,0.5f);
                    gl.glPointSize(10);
                    gl.glBegin(GL.GL_POINTS);
                    gl.glVertex2i(i, j);
                }
                else if(volumeData[i][j][0] < 240)
                {
                    gl.glColor3f(0.0f,0.0f,0.6f);
                    gl.glPointSize(10);
                    gl.glBegin(GL.GL_POINTS);
                    gl.glVertex2i(i, j);
                }
                else if(volumeData[i][j][0] < 280)
                {
                    gl.glColor3f(0.0f,0.0f,0.7f);
                    gl.glPointSize(10);
                    gl.glBegin(GL.GL_POINTS);
                    gl.glVertex2i(i, j);
                }
            }
        }
```

marschnerlobb.raw.gz is the dataset that I am currently using to test my program which can be found at http://www.volvis.org/

When I run the program at first I thought it was correct as it looked like it may be a a slice from the dataset I used (which resembles a square). But when I tried it with a different dataset (a skull) the result being displayed was still a square image.

Comment: Why not using Jzy3D? It is based on JOGL, it works very well. It's typically designed for this kind of purpose.

Comment: @gouessej its a piece of school work and we're required to use JOGL

Comment: I don't want to be harsh, you can ask some help here but we won't do your homework. You should set an initial maximum value to an unreachable value rather than 0 and you should do the same for the minimal value. You seem to look at the same slice, is it intentional? volumeData[i][j][0] 0?